# Multiple RewriteRules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a conventional site to which I've added Wordpress which is installed in /wp and rewritten to root. I also have a perl program which needs a rewrite rule. I understand that I should not have two instances of RewriteBase but cannot see how to get the two sections working together. With the current setup, the virtual directory /amazon results in a 404 for all calls when the WP section is active.

Removing the second rewritebase has no effect.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(amazon)$ $1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^(amazon)/(.*)(\.[a-z]+)$ cgi-bin/cbooks/ca.pl?virtual=$2&virtual.dir=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(amazon)/(.*)$ cgi-bin/cbooks/ca.pl?virtual=$2&virtual.dir=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your amazon rules *before* your wordpress routing rules and add a leading slash to the rule's target making them absolute URL-paths:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^amazon$ /$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^amazon/(.*)(\.[a-z]+)$ /cgi-bin/cbooks/ca.pl?virtual=$2&virtual.dir=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^amazon/(.*)$ /cgi-bin/cbooks/ca.pl?virtual=$2&virtual.dir=$1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The wordpress routing rules are routing your amazon rules because they come first.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you!!!! I found this answer via Google as I must have not ticked the email answer box (if there is one).

Comment: @RussellWhite you should mark the answer as correct so that your question is listed as resolved